# Plot a change point curve in one command

Tags: r, plot, curve

I want to plot a curve that has a change point at `x=5`

Until now I am using the code

```
curve(exp(0.68+0.92*x), from=0,to=5, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=c(0,500))
curve(exp(0.68+0.92*x-0.7*(x-5)), from=5,to=12, add=T)
```

Is it possible to write it in one line (one `curve` command)? I was thinking

something like this

```
curve(exp(0.47+0.8*x-0.7*(x-5)*if(x<5,0,1)), from=0,to=12, xlim=c(0,12), ylim=c(0,500))
```

but it doesn't work for R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ifelse` you can create one data series:

```
values = ifelse(x <= 5, exp(0.68+0.92*x), exp(0.68+0.92*x-0.7*(x-5))
```

and plot them:

```
curve(values)
```

and if you insist on a one-liner you can combine the `ifelse` and the call to `curve`:

```
curve(ifelse(x <= 5, exp(0.68+0.92*x), exp(0.68+0.92*x-0.7*(x-5)))
```

although separating the code into two lines makes it easier to read imo.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a function that plots both curves:

```
myfun <- function(...) {
 plot(...)
 lines(...)
}
```

You have to give the right arguments of course. The result is two curves in one plot